# How to add reminder in calendar

Tags: android, android-widget

Hi i am implementing birthday reminder app on android. please tell me what is the procedure to set reminder on calendar. I have obtained the calendar in android .

Comment: jayesh, use 'content://calendar/reminders' uri for inserting reminder in ContentProvider?

Comment: Is this your problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for adding events in the Android Calendar.

```
GregorianCalendar startDate = new GregorianCalendar(Locale.ENGLISH);
            startDate = CustomDateFormatter.formatScheduleDate(schedule.getScheduleStartDate());

            GregorianCalendar endDate = new GregorianCalendar(Locale.ENGLISH);
            endDate = CustomDateFormatter.formatScheduleDate(schedule.getScheduleEndDate());

            try{

                String[] projection = new String[] { "_id", "name" };
                Uri calendars = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");
                Cursor managedCursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(calendars, projection, "selected=1", null, null);
                ContentValues event = new ContentValues();

                long StartTime = startDate.getTimeInMillis();
                long EndTime = endDate.getTimeInMillis();
//              int nameColumn = managedCursor.getColumnIndex("name"); 
                int idColumn = managedCursor.getColumnIndex("_id");

                if(managedCursor.moveToFirst()){

//                  String calName = managedCursor.getString(nameColumn);
                    String calId = managedCursor.getString(idColumn);

//                  Log.e("Cal name", calName);

                    event.put("calendar_id", calId);
                    event.put("title", schedule.getScheduleType());
                    event.put("description", schedule.getScheduleTextContent());
                    event.put("dtstart", StartTime );
                    event.put("dtend", EndTime);
                    event.put("hasAlarm", 1);

                    Uri eventsUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
                    Uri calUri = mContext.getContentResolver().insert(eventsUri, event);

                    Uri remindersUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/reminders");
                    event = new ContentValues();
                    event.put("event_id", Long.parseLong(calUri.getLastPathSegment()));
//                  Log.d("Event ID: ", calUri.getLastPathSegment());

                    event.put("method",1);
                    event.put("minutes",0);

                    mContext.getContentResolver().insert(remindersUri, event);
                }

                managedCursor.close();

            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Contact me if you have any problems.